# setcookie(): Argument #3 returns a string instead of an int or array after login on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, typeerror, setcookie

I am totally new on Wordpress php, and I have taken over from a previous developer. I have been working on it for 4 months now and I have encountered an issue after I updated PHP from 7.4 to 8.0 and Wordpress from 5.6 to 6.0. I have this error showing on the admin side when I login and I can't access anything on the admin dashboard there after:

**"Tpye Error Thrown: setcookie(): Argument #3 ($expires_or_options) must be of type array|int, string given"**

My colleague, who never seems to log out, was not getting this error. He created several  new users for us to test if this is occurring for each one of those users. It turns out that even the new users have the same issue after they login. The admin dashboard can not be accessed. Every time I try to access for something like "menus" or "widgets" i get the same error.

**"Tpye Error Thrown: setcookie(): Argument #3 ($expires_or_options) must be of type array|int, string given"**

I don't know where this error is coming from but did some research of my own and I came across a few sources that mentioned that the issue could be on the the plugins or the options file in this directory "../wp-includes/option.php". I'm not certain of these attempts but I had to try and get this resolved. Also, just to mention, I have made backups of the site before the attempts.

**Attempt 1:**
I set down with my colleague, whose account is not affected, and we disabled plugins in order and activated one by one to identify where the error was but the results were the same. I still had the same error when I login with my creds and the new users created for testing.

**Attempt 2:**
I backed up the original options.php file before and tried to edit Argument #3 of the function setcookie(). I replaced the #3 argument with the value 0. that also did not work so I returned the original file as it was.

```
// The cookie is not set in the current browser or the saved value is newer.
    $secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( admin_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, 0, null, $secure );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), 0, null, $secure );
    $_COOKIE[ 'wp-settings-' . $user_id ] = $settings;
```

I recently found out that the function setcookie() has an alternative signature on this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php which i have not tried yet. I will give it a try as well, perhaps it may come right. I have posted on the forum because I am not certain of which other attempt I should look into to solve this. Please, if there is anyone that can help get back to dashboard without this error, please do.
Thank you all.

Comment: The error message should have included a specific file and line number to checkout

Comment: @ChrisHaas. Good day sir. The message above is the only thing that appears on the screen after I log in. No file or line number indicated. I'm not sure what which file could be causing this

Comment: Is WP_DEBUG turned on? You should be getting an error such as https://3v4l.org/l7CkR

Comment: oh, I just saw how to turn WP_DEBUG on the wordpress site. I checked on the wp_config.php and I had these lines: ```ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );```

Comment: If you turn on display, or check the log file, you should have a line number with the problem

Comment: @ChrisHaas apologies sir, had some power issues on my side. I managed to located the debug.log file just after i turned on the display error option. I then logged at exactly 22-Oct-2022 22:47:00 to see if the error will be logged. I had the same error on my screen without the file and line number indicated. However, i did check the log and found the below.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6fSklC9PJhVcHnRUTdKcYdR9zwF5C6J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We tried disabling plugin and activating them one-by-one with my colleague but nothing worked. I have tried everything at this point and im not sure why this is happening. I am still getting ```"Tpye Error Thrown: setcookie(): Argument #3 ($expires_or_options) must be of type array|int, string given"```when i login with my account